# Two "if" conditions in the same time

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am writing a script to bring me data from other nodes via ssh in a multi selection choice menu, and i want to display a message according to this data.

```
if [[ "$option" == "1" ]]
then
  ssh skyusr@<IP> "export JAVA_HOME=/opt/mesosphere && /var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/*/frameworks/*/executors/*/runs/latest/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/bin/nodetool -p 7199 status" | sed -n '6,10p' | awk '{print $1,$2}' | grep DN > $file_name
  if [ -s $file_name ]
  then
    echo "All Cassandra Nodes are UP !"
  else cat "$file_name"
  fi
fi
```

When i execute the script, i see it does not see the second if condition to display the message .

What is the correct syntax ?

Comment: How do you "see it does not see the second if condition"? Have you tried running it with `set -xv`?

Answer (score 0):

There is, as far as I can see, nothing wrong with the syntax. You might want to do something about spacing etc. to enhance readability, but that is it.

I assumed, that `file_name` is set somewhere before this part, as is option.

If things do not work as you expect them to work, you can add some statements for debugging purposes, which you must remove later on. For example, in this case, I would like to see the output of the `ssh` and add some echo's to see the flow-control:

```
if [[ "$option" == "1" ]] ; then
    ssh skyusr@<IP> "export JAVA_HOME=/opt/mesosphere && /var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/*/frameworks/*/executors/*/runs/latest/apache-cassandra-3.0.10/bin/nodetool -p 7199 status" > tempfile
    cat tempfile |
      sed -n '6,10p' |
      awk '{print $1,$2}' |
      grep DN > "$file_name"
    if [ -s "$file_name" ] ; then
        echo "All Cassandra Nodes are UP !"
    else
        echo "$file_name is not empty"
        cat "$file_name"
    fi
fi
```

You can use the `tempfile` to verify that your `sed`, `awk`, `grep` combination acts correctly.